# After Facebook installa facebook app redirects me to the url but outside of Facebook

Tags: facebook

I have the following problem:

I'm trying to do my first application for Facebook and after Facebook connection and install the application not automatically redirects me to the url but outside of Facebook. This only happens the first time, once it has been installed if the url is recharged and stays within Facebook.

Any ideas to fix it?

I do not know if the problem is the code or application configuration:(

```
// PHP SDK v.3.0.0 de Facebook    
require 'includes/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '*******',
  'secret' => '*************',
));
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {
  try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    $me =  $facebook->api('/me');

  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
                'scope' => 'read_stream,publish_stream,user_about_me,user_likes,email,user_status'
            ));
}
 if (!$user) {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
        exit;
    } 
?>
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>
    <title>php-sdk 3.0.0</title>
        <style typ="text/css">
            html, body { width: 520px;}
        </style>    
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>php-sdk</h1>
    <h3>PHP Session</h3>
      <?php foreach($_SESSION as $key=>$value){
          echo '<strong>' . $key . '</strong> => ' . $value . '<br />';
      }
      ?>
      <h3>Tu</h3>
      <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user; ?>/picture">
      <h3>Tus datos (/me)</h3>
      <?php foreach($user_profile as $key=>$value){
          echo '<strong>' . $key . '</strong> => ' . $value . '<br />';
      }
      ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify a `redirect_uri` in your `getLoginUrl` method and hence the SDK constructed one for you that is based on your current URL.

So all you need to do is just set the canvas URL as your `redirect_uri`:

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'scope' => 'read_stream,publish_stream,user_about_me,user_likes,email,user_status',
    'redirect_uri' => 'CANVAS_URL'
));
```

P.S: `$user_profile` and `$me` holds the same value, just use one of them instead of making two Graph API calls.

Comment: Thanks!
If I put that line of code is not finish loading and display the page.
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
                'scope' => 'read_stream,publish_stream,user_about_me,user_likes,email,user_status',
    'redirect_uri' => 'http://apps.facebook.com/promocion_orange/'
            ));
I have seen that the problem is just when does rediección to "like" that is when the domain:


  if (!$MeGusta){
   
   //referrerIsFacebookApp();
   echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location = 'megusta.php';</script>";
  }

Any suggestions?

Comment: I didn't get your point here, could you update your questions with a formatted code and *proper* english?